# Cannot read property 'split' of undefined (debugging issue)

Tags: javascript, html

I am having difficulty figuring out the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="content" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
            
                <p>Please select your preferred payment method.</p>
            <div class="radio">
            <label>
                                                        <input type="radio" name="payment_method" value="authorizenet" checked="checked">
                                Credit Card/Debit Card (Authorize.Net)                            </label>
        </div>
            <div class="radio">
            <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="payment_method" value="affirm">
                                Credit Card/Debit Card (Affirm)                            </label>
        </div>
    <p><strong>Add comments about your order.</strong></p>
<p>
    <textarea name="comment" rows="8" class="form-control"></textarea>
</p>
<div class="cart-module">
    <div class="cart-content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <h4 for="input-coupon">Coupon Code</h4>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" name="coupon" value="" placeholder="Coupon Code" id="input-coupon" class="form-control">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <input type="button" value="Apply" data-code="coupon" data-loading-text="Loading..." class="btn btn-primary">
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <h4 for="input-voucher">Gift Certificate Code</h4>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" name="voucher" value="" placeholder="Gift Certificate Code" id="input-voucher" class="form-control">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <input type="button" value="Apply" data-code="voucher" data-loading-text="Loading..." class="btn btn-primary">
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <div class="pull-right">I have read and agree to the <a href="https://hhtruckaccessories.com?route=information%2Finformation%2Fagree&amp;information_id=5" class="agree"><b>Shipping and Returns</b></a>.                            <input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="1">
                        &nbsp;
            <input type="button" value="Continue" id="button-payment-method" data-loading-text="Loading..." class="btn btn-primary">
        </div>
    </div>
```

The Script:

```
var newtext = "affirm";
selector = $("input[type=radio][value=affirm]").closest("label");
var line = selector.html().split(">")[0] + ">" + newtext;

selector.html(line);
```

The Goal:

I have two radio buttons on the checkout page.

1. Credit Card/Debit Card (Authorize.Net)
2. Credit Card/Debit Card (Affirm)

I am unable to edit the HTML directly.  Thus rebuilding the html line with the above code to give me the output I want.   I am trying to change the HTML text of the 2nd radio input to just "Affirm".

The script works in a fiddle, but not on the page.

Comment: You are not **defining** (or **declaring** depending on your school of thought)  `selector` in your code --  You are simply **setting** it. `var selector = ` or `const selector =`

Comment: How and where do you load this script? If you load this in the header, the DOM is not created yet, thus selector won't find any elements.

Comment: @derpirscher - I have added this to the body end.

Comment: @Zak - I have defined it as well and it still gives me the same error.  I have done a console.log($("input[type=radio][value=affirm]").closest("label").length); to make sure it was correct too.

Answer (score 0):

I once encountered a similar bug when trying to maintain a page without access to the source files. I was using jQuery to attempt to delete a p element sentence but was coming up undefined because it was running on the homepage before the application even got to generate that part of the html. It was an SPA. I fixed it by adding a listener on the document to the router something along like this: `$(document).on("pageshow", "#checkoutPage", function() {//your jquery function});`

---

I tried it both on CodePen and locally with VS Code and both time I got the intended effect. Have you tried maybe making sure youre using the right version of JQuery and that is linked to the html in the proper oder, also debugging via console logs? See below:

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/bangulo/pen/wvgPqjE?editors=0011)

```
enter code here
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I'm using https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js  - and it should be in the right order.  I am at a total loss man :(

Comment: This is my checkout page if you want to take a look (bit.ly/3teD3vD).

Comment: I just checked it out. Its a weird bug but I actually a somewhat similar bug at work not long ago. I will update my answer lmk if its helpful.

Comment: Thanks brains219.  I'll keep trying.  I bet it's definitely something to do with the accordion.